# Combination of vectors problem

Tags: probability, vectors, combinations

So the question asks:

Consider vectors $(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ for which $x_i ∈ {1, 2, \ldots , n}$ and $k ≥ 1$.

(a) How many vectors satisfy $x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_k?$

(b) How many vectors satisfy $x_1 ≤ x_2 ≤ \cdots ≤ x_k$?

So I am thinking to use the combination formula is $C =n!/[r!(n-r)!]$

But since I don't know which is larger n or k, I don't know if it choosing n from k or choosing k from n, so is the solution

$$ \frac 1{[k!/[n!(k-n)!]]} = \frac{n!(k-n)!}{k!} $$

or  $$ \frac 1{[n!/[k!(n-k)!]]} = \frac{k!(n-k)!}{n!} \text{ ?} $$

And for part b, the textbook says it is $(k-1)^{(k-1)} $over the total combinations. The doubt about the total combination holds, still. And how to get $(k-1)^{(k-1)}$?

Comment: Are we to assume that $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k}$ are integers? Because if they're just real vectors, there are continuum many.

Comment: @AJY: the question says that the $x_i \in 1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: For (a) you are choosing $k$ from $n$ and once you've made that choice there is a unique way of ordering the $x_i$. The fact that $C^n_k = 0$ when $k > n$ looks after the impossible cases. For (b), you need to say more about what your textbook actually says if you want help with understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

For case a) the answer is$$\binom{n}{k},n\geq k$$ because we choose $k$ diferent terms from $n$ different at all and that is combination without repetitions.

For case b) the answer is $$\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$ there each term can be repetead at most $k$ times and there we have combination with repetitions

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition for more information.